# How do I find the derivative of $a^x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The homework question I have is find the derivative of $8^{log_2(x)}$ but we haven't learn't how to find the derivative of a function where the variable is the power of a constant. How do I do this?

Comment: Does 'log2(x)' mean $\log_2(x)$?  If so, you can simplify the expression for you function to something that is not of the form $a^x$.

Comment: As for the derivative of $a^x$, notice that $a^x=e^{x \ln a}$, which is the form you are familiar about. However in this question, you don't need to do it by finding out derivative of $a^x$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where logarithmic differentiation can make life easier. After going to natural logarithms as faze2 did, you the have
$$y={8}^{\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}}$$ Taking logarithms of both sides $$\log(y)=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}\log(8)=3\log(x)$$ Now, differentiating both sides $$\frac{y'}y=\frac{3}x$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

You can use the same trick wiyh more complex expressions; let us consider $$y=f(x)^{g(x)}$$ Doing the same $$\log(y)=g(x)\log\big(f(x)\big)$$ Differentiate using the chain rule $$\frac{y'}y=g'(x)\log\big(f(x)\big)+g(x)\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$ and then, finally, $$y'=f(x)^{g(x)} \left(\frac{g(x) f'(x)}{f(x)}+\log (f(x)) g'(x)\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\displaystyle8^{(\log_2x)}=(2^3)^{(\log_2x)}=\left(2^{\log_2x}\right)^3$$

If $\displaystyle\log_2x=y,x=2^y=2^{\log_2x}$

Comment: By far the easiest, most direct answer: to realize that $\;8^{\log_2x}=x^3\;$ , so it's derivate is boringly $\;3x^2\;$ !+1

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it:

$$\frac{d}{dx}8^{\log _2\left(x\right)}$$
$$8^{\log _2\left(x\right)}=e^{\log _2\left(x\right)\ln \left(8\right)}$$

$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{\log _2\left(x\right)\ln \left(8\right)}\right)$$

Then, apply the chain rule: $\frac{df\left(u\right)}{dx}=\frac{df}{du}\cdot \frac{du}{dx}$

$\mathrm{Let\:}\log _2\left(x\right)\ln \left(8\right)=u$

$$=\frac{d}{du}\left(e^u\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log _2\left(x\right)\ln \left(8\right)\right)$$

Apply the common derivative:

$$\frac{d}{du}\left(e^u\right)=e^u$$

Then, take the constant out:

$$=\ln \left(8\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log _2\left(x\right)\right)$$

Apply the common derivative: $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log _2\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{1}{x\ln \left(2\right)}$

$$=\ln \left(8\right)\frac{1}{x\ln \left(2\right)}$$

Simplify to $$=\frac{3}{x}$$

$$=e^u\frac{3}{x}$$

Substitute back to $u=\log _2\left(x\right)\ln \left(8\right)$

$$=e^{\log _2\left(x\right)\ln \left(8\right)}\frac{3}{x}$$

$$=\frac{3\cdot \:8^{\log _2\left(x\right)}}{x}$$

Here's a visual:

[image]